# How to ignore force push?

Tags: git

How to know in pre-receive hook that commit has been pushed with 
--force option? I want to block force push and allow only force-with-lease push on the reomte repository.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you really care about the `--force` option (which might be given even when it isn't required), or do you want to ensure that pushes are all fast-forward?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!If you want to block force push this should not be done client side. You'd better set this on the remote repository. It is usually possible to decline force push actions on remote repositories. What type of system is the remote running on? Give us some more context please.

Comment: I want to use always --force-with-lease instead of --force to avoide this:  "If somebody else built on top of your original history while you are rebasing, the tip of the branch at the remote may advance with her commit, and blindly pushing with --force will lose her work.

Comment: I want to do it on the remote repository, but I don't know how. The remote running on  the server with ssh access on Linux System.

Answer (score 3):

In git there are two methods to do that. You can set in the configuration the following parameters.

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
receive.denyDeletes
```

Or you can use a hook like mentioned. There should be a template hook called `update-paranoid` you can use that hook that should do what you need.

[Git update-paranoid Hook](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/hooks?id=080cbc1275ac09445136ba429d90b5ec85e92c1c)